# Why am I getting a result opposite from what I expected?

Tags: java, binary-tree, subtree

I wrote a code to figure out whether a small binary tree t1 is a subtree of t2. 
I am supposed to get `true` as the result but I am getting the opposite.

Here is my code:

```
class Node {
    int val;
    Node left, right;
    public Node(int v) {
        val = v;
        left = right = null;
    }
}
public class BT {
    Node root;
    public BT() {
        root = null;
    }
    public boolean containsTree(Node t1, Node t2) {
        StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder();
        getOrderString(t1, s1);
        getOrderString(t2, s2);
        return s1.indexOf(s2.toString()) != -1;
    }
    public void getOrderString(Node t, StringBuilder s) {
        if (t == null) {
            s.append("X");
            return;
        }
        s.append(t.val);
        getOrderString(t.left, s);
        getOrderString(t.right, s);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BT bt = new BT();
        bt.root = new Node(10);
        bt.root.left = new Node(12);
        bt.root.right = new Node(15);
        bt.root.left.left = new Node(25);
        bt.root.left.right = new Node(30);
        bt.root.right.left = new Node(36);
        BT bt2 = new BT();
        bt2.root = new Node(10);
        bt2.root.left = new Node(12);
        bt2.root.right = new Node(15);
        bt2.root.left.left = new Node(25);
        System.out.println(bt.containsTree(bt.root, bt2.root));
    }
}
```

Could anyone explain to me why i am getting false?

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Comment: You're getting false because it's not a subtree. Your first tree doesn't contain the second.

Comment: Andy, can you be more specific? I don't see what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2nd tree is not the subtree of 1st one. That's why it returns false so your code is actually correct :)

[image: First and Second Trees]

Answer (score 0):

Your API for constructing the tree is hard to read. If you defined a constructor:

```
public Node(int v, Node left, Node right)
```

Then you could declare your trees as:

```
bt.root = new Node(
    10,
    new Node(
        12,
        new Node(25, null, null),
        new Node(30, null, null)),
    new Node(
        25,
        new Node(36, null, null),
        null));

bt2.root = new Node(
    10,
    new Node(
        12,
        new Node(25, null, null),
        null)),
    new Node(15, null, null));
```

Like this, I think it is easy to see that the second isn't a subtree of the first:

- the node with value 10 in the first has a right node with value 25; in the second it has a right value 15;
- the node with value 12 in the first has a non-null right value, whereas it is null in the second.